# Using Python CDK, allow API Gateway to pass request to Lambda function's specific alias via the stageVariables

Tags: aws-cdk

I have the following stack file where `create_lambda_function()` is the most important part.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('api/lambda_fns'))

import importlib
from glob import glob
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_iam as _iam,
    aws_apigateway as _gateway
)
from utils.lambda_fn_configs import Role


class ApiStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        self.db_read_write_role = _iam.Role.from_role_arn(
            self,
            'LambdaDynamodbLimitedReadWrite',
            '<some_arn_that_is_masked>',
        )

        self.db_read_only_role = _iam.Role.from_role_arn(
            self,
            'LambdaDynamodbReadOnly',
            '<some_arn_that_is_masked>',
        )

        self.layer = _lambda.LayerVersion(
            self, 
            'DependenciesLayer',
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset('dependencies'),
            compatible_runtimes=[_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9],
            description='Layer with all dependencies',
        )

        self.api = _gateway.RestApi(
            self,
            'BE_API',
            rest_api_name='BE API',
            deploy_options=_gateway.StageOptions(
                stage_name='prd',
                variables={
                    'alias': 'prd',
                }
            ),
        )
        
        _gateway.Stage(
            self,
            'stg',
            deployment=self.api.latest_deployment,
            stage_name='stg',
            variables={
                'alias': 'stg',
            }
        )

        handlers = self.get_handlers()

        for handler in handlers:
            self.create_lambda_function(handler)


    def get_handlers(self):
        path = '*/lambda_fns/*/handler.py'
        files = [f for f in glob(path, recursive=True) if 'utils' not in f]
        handlers = []
        for file in files:
            function_name = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(file))
            function_name_pascal = f'{function_name.title().replace("_", "")}'
            path = f"{function_name}.handler"
            module = importlib.import_module(path)
            configs = module.configs
            handlers.append({
                'function_name': function_name_pascal,
                'handler_path': path,
                'configs': configs,
            })
        return handlers
    

    def get_role(self, role_enum):
        if (role_enum == Role.DB_READ_WRITE):
            return self.db_read_write_role
        elif (role_enum == Role.DB_READ_ONLY):
            return self.db_read_only_role
        else:
            raise Exception('Handler does not have a proper role configured')
    

    def create_lambda_function(self, handler):
        configs = handler['configs']
        role = self.get_role(configs['role'])
        func_name = handler["function_name"]
        func_path = handler["handler_path"]

        # define lambda function
        fn = _lambda.Function(
            self,
            func_name,
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset('api/lambda_fns'),
            handler=f'{func_path}.handle',
            layers=[self.layer],
            role=role,
        )

        apigateway_configs = configs['aws_apigateway']
        if 'method' in apigateway_configs and 'route' in apigateway_configs:
            resource = self.api.root.add_resource(apigateway_configs['route'])
            resource.add_method(
                apigateway_configs['method'].value,
                _gateway.LambdaIntegration(fn),
            )

        # add stg alias
        _lambda.Alias(
            self,
            f"{func_name}StgAlias",
            alias_name='stg',
            version=fn.latest_version
        )
```

Above code isn't really doing what I want. Here is a list of what I want.

- In API Gateway, I want 2 stages: `prd` and `stg`
- When API is accessed via `https://XXX.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/stg`, I want the proxied Lambda function's `stg` alias version to be executed.
- When API is accessed via `https://XXX.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/prd`, I want the proxied Lambda function's `prd` alias version to be executed.

I can see these setup in AWS Console.

[image]

Above `/user - GET` method is missing in the `Lambda Function` the `:${stageVariables.alias}` and I have no idea how to achieve this in CDK.

And my lambda function for that end-point has 2 triggers added. I can see `prd` is there but `stg` isn't there.

[image]

My lambda versions and aliases are setup correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for my problem has been found after many hours.

- Integration has to be passed at the time when `add_method()` is called on the API Gateway resource
- Appropriate permissions need to be added to the lambda function AND its aliases

Here is the working source code for the CDK stack file.

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('api/lambda_fns'))

import importlib
from glob import glob
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_iam as _iam,
    aws_apigateway as _gateway
)
from utils.lambda_fn_configs import Role
from api.configs import AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER


class ApiStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        self.db_read_write_role = _iam.Role.from_role_arn(
            self,
            'LambdaDynamodbLimitedReadWrite',
            f'arn:aws:iam::{AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:role/LambdaDynamodbLimitedReadWrite',
        )

        self.db_read_only_role = _iam.Role.from_role_arn(
            self,
            'LambdaDynamodbReadOnly',
            f'arn:aws:iam::{AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:role/LambdaDynamodbReadOnly',
        )

        self.layer = _lambda.LayerVersion(
            self, 
            'DependenciesLayer',
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset('dependencies'),
            compatible_runtimes=[_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9],
            description='Layer with all dependencies',
        )

        self.api = _gateway.RestApi(
            self,
            'BE_API',
            rest_api_name='BE API',
            deploy_options=_gateway.StageOptions(
                stage_name='prd',
                variables={
                    'alias': 'prd',
                }
            ),
        )
        
        _gateway.Stage(
            self,
            'stg',
            deployment=self.api.latest_deployment,
            stage_name='stg',
            variables={
                'alias': 'stg',
            }
        )

        handlers = self.get_handlers()

        for handler in handlers:
            self.create_lambda_function(handler)


    def get_handlers(self):
        path = '*/lambda_fns/*/handler.py'
        files = [f for f in glob(path, recursive=True) if 'utils' not in f]
        handlers = []
        for file in files:
            function_name = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(file))
            function_name_pascal = f'{function_name.title().replace("_", "")}'
            path = f"{function_name}.handler"
            module = importlib.import_module(path)
            configs = module.configs

            handlers.append({
                'function_name': function_name_pascal,
                'handler_path': path,
                'configs': configs,
            })
        return handlers
    

    def get_role(self, role_enum):
        if (role_enum == Role.DB_READ_WRITE):
            return self.db_read_write_role
        elif (role_enum == Role.DB_READ_ONLY):
            return self.db_read_only_role
        else:
            raise Exception('Handler does not have a proper role configured')
    

    def create_lambda_function(self, handler):
        configs = handler['configs']
        role = self.get_role(configs['role'])
        func_name = handler["function_name"]
        func_path = handler["handler_path"]

        fn = _lambda.Function(
            self,
            func_name,
            runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9,
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset('api/lambda_fns'),
            handler=f'{func_path}.handle',
            layers=[self.layer],
            role=role,
        )

        stg_alias = _lambda.Alias(
            self,
            f"{func_name}StgAlias",
            alias_name='stg',
            version=fn.latest_version
        )

        prd_alias = _lambda.Alias(
            self,
            f"{func_name}PrdAlias",
            alias_name='prd',
            version=fn.latest_version
        )

        apigateway_configs = configs['aws_apigateway']
        route = apigateway_configs['route']
        resource = self.api.root.add_resource(route)

        api_uri = (
            f"arn:aws:apigateway:"
            f"eu-west-2"
            f":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/"
            f"{fn.function_arn}"
            f":"
            f"${{stageVariables.alias}}"
            f"/invocations"
        )

        api_http_method=apigateway_configs['method'].value

        api_to_lambda_integration = _gateway.Integration(
            type=_gateway.IntegrationType.AWS_PROXY,
            integration_http_method='POST', # MUST BE HARDCODED TO POST!!!
            uri=api_uri,
        )

        resource.add_method(
            api_http_method,
            integration=api_to_lambda_integration,
        )

        service_principal = _iam.ServicePrincipal('apigateway.amazonaws.com')

        fn.add_permission(
            func_name+'LambdaPermission',
            principal=service_principal,
            action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
            source_arn=f"arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-2:{AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:{self.api.rest_api_id}/*/*/*",
        )
        
        stg_alias.add_permission(
            func_name+'LambdaAliasStgPermission',
            principal=service_principal,
            action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
            source_arn=f"arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-2:{AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:{self.api.rest_api_id}/*/*/*",
        )

        prd_alias.add_permission(
            func_name+'LambdaAliasPrdPermission',
            principal=service_principal,
            action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
            source_arn=f"arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-2:{AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:{self.api.rest_api_id}/*/*/*",
        )
```